# Blazor broken syntax coloring

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, blazor

I experienced strange syntax coloring problems in my Blazor project. Does anyone have any idea what can cause it?

in the @code part:

[image: @code]

in the html part:

[image: html]

I already tried cleaning and rebuilding. Also, deleted each bin folder.

Comment: restarting vs usually works for me

Comment: There's really not much you can do but jiggle it, bump it, and turn it off and on.  Try deleting config files, delete your bin folder, etc.

Comment: Does not work :(

Comment: Close the tab and open it back up.

Comment: Nope. No luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, it didn't work the first time but finally, the problem disappeared.

I cleaned the solution, removed all "bin" and "obj" folders, and rebuilt the solution again.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can make it mark so that it can help more people